# I need to Export / Transfer a discontinued Google Chrome Extension between computers

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy an extension from one Chrome installation to another?](https://superuser.com/questions/462804/how-to-copy-an-extension-from-one-chrome-installation-to-another)

I have a great extension on one of my computers, that for whatever reason the developer decided to pull from the Google WebStore so I can't download it from there (and the developer has a personal website of the typical "could care less about others" design, and I can't find it if it even is available there).

The developer did pull it himself, it wasn't Google that disallowed the extension for some weird reason. This is something I am wondering in general if it's even possible? Did Google design Chrome in such a way that I can't get extensions except through the WebStore? Is it impossible to manually transfer a file from my source computer to the target computer, and install the extension that way?

I'm worried that if I set up Sync, the extension will be lost forever, I'd at least want to be able to back up the extension somehow first.

In my case I'm transferring from a Mac to Windows, but I'm hoping we can find a universal method.

Comment: @soandos I saw that, thank you for linking it. But I'm assuming it won't work because the code pasted there (to import) calls on "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/" to download the extensions. I'll have to double check. And I'm transferring from a Mac to Windows.

Comment: The second part does not matter at all. Try an it and see.

Answer (score 3):

- Do a Windows Explorer search for the CRX extension.
- In the search results, *select all*
- Right click and create a zip file
- On the Mac, copy the zip file via USB, network sharing or by sending it per mail
- Backup your Google profile first (the `~/Library/Application Support/Google` directory)
- Then open Google Chrome and Finder
- In Finder, open the folder where you unzipped your file, thus the `.crx` files
- Now drag from Finder to the Google Chrome window. A message – usually at the status bar – will ask you whether to install or not.