# How to copy an extension from one Chrome installation to another?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

''**In the absence of web**'' can be added to the title.

I have not tried to sync Chrome among my systems. My friend was not able to add an extension (YouTube Downloader). But I added it to my browser sometime before. So I tried to copy the `.crx` file and install in the other computer. Chrome notified me that "Using Chrome Web Store only you can install".

So how can I install in the other system?

Comment: i found this question relevant after Evernote shut down it's "Clearly" extension. I wan't it to migrate from my office laptop to personal laptop.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You *should* be able to install the `.crx` file, but you may need to try a few things.

- First, if you simply drag the `.crx` file to the browser window, you should see a notice at the bottom of the page asking you to confirm. If you click *Confirm*, it should ask you to install. If that does not work, try creating a simple `.html` file that has an anchor (`<a>` tag) with an `href` pointing to the `.crx` file:

  extension

  Put the `.html` file in the same location as the `.crx` file and open it. Click the link and see if Chrome allows you to install it like that.

  If it does not, you can try running a local webserver and serving the file from there (I know I have does this at least once before).

---

- Another (probably easier) option is to extract the `.crx` file (using [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) for example). Open the extensions page (`chrome://extensions/`), click the *Developer mode* check-box, and then *Load unpacked extension…*:

  [image]

---

- Finally, you could manually copy the extension, but it is somewhat of a pain in the butt:

  1. Open the extensions page (`chrome://extensions/`)
  2. Click the *Developer mode* check-box
  3. Examine the ID of the extension (long string of letters next to `ID:`)
  4. Open the [User Data Directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory), then the `Extensions` directory
  5. Copy the folder with the same name as the extensions’s ID to the `Extensions` folder of the target system
  6. Open the file `Preferences` in the User Data Directory in a text editor
  7. Find the section containing the extension (do a search for the ID)
  8. Copy the whole section, making sure to match braces correctly, for example:

     ```
     "jchfimlohbodnpamghfgfgabbnfajpbe": {
       "from_bookmark": false,
       "from_webstore": false,
       …
       "path": "jchfimlohbodnpamghfgfgabbnfajpbe\\2012.6.9_0",
       "state": 1
     },
     ```
  9. Paste the extension in the `Preferences` file of the target computer. **Check the trailing comma ( the `},` at the end of the block).** If the block you pasted is the last one (i.e., the next line is a single brace one indent back), then you must remove the comma, but if it is another block, then you must make sure it’s there (it’s obvious whether you need it or not when you actually paste it)
  10. Save the file (you may want to make a backup of `Preferences` and maybe even your whole `Extensions` directory) and run Chrome

---

- These were options for copying general extensions, but for extensions specifically for downloading YouTube videos, I recommend forgoing extensions altogether (which usually run in a whole separate process) and using the [YousableTubeFix](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/57201) user-script.

  It adds a *Download* button to YouTube videos, but it also lets you configure what you do or do not want on the page as well. For example, many people will want to get rid of the comments section and/or the related-videos section, and YousableTubeFix lets you do that as well.

  YousableTubeFix also lets you configure YouTube videos to **not** automatically start buffering and playing, which is *extremely* useful.

  And because it’s a script, it only runs when necessary, so it does not use up extra memory when browsing other sites and also does not require the Web Store and can simply be saved/installed/etc.

[image]

Comment: @Synetech I clicked unpack, pointed it to ddfsfsdsf within the extensions directory, and got an error  "manifest file is missing or unreadable" so I clicked unpack, I pointed it to sdfdsfdsfddssd\7.0  and it said "could not load extension from..."  The 'manifest_version' key must be present and set to 2(without quotes..."  So I edited manifest.json but I still get that error.  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sjRkg4VK

Comment: I recall something about newer versions of Chrome getting more locked down recently and making the extension requirements stricter, so it might accept fewer extensions than before. I’ll run some tests on Tuesday.

Comment: @Synetech thanks, here's the extension i'm trying. it's called "tab menu" i've zipped the folder from a computer it's installed on galfofdpepkcahkfobimileafiobdplb.zip  I can't install it onto my other machine   http://ge.tt/6BKTsdk/v/0

Comment: @barlop, I just tried it in Chromium 11 and it installed just fine (when I pointed it to the `7_0` folder). I’ll try it out on a newer, locked-down version soon.

Comment: @barlop, I just tried it in a new version of Chrome and it loaded just fine (again, pointing it to the `7_0` folder). Try renaming the [User Data Directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) so that Chrome creates a fresh, empty profile. If it can be loaded, then it is a problem with your user profile.

Comment: @Synetech - Is this still a valid working way?

Comment: I can say that the second method (load unpacked extension in Developer mode) is still working on 2020; tested on Chrome 75 & Chrome 80.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Windows 7, copy them from `C:\Users\your-username\AppData\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`, and then paste them into the same folder on another computer. Replace `your-username` with your username.

If you're not worried about your privacy, you can synchronise all of your data, extensions, and settings anyway. To do it, click the wrench icon  and then select **Sign in to Chromium...**, but you'll need a Google account to start with.

Comment: Link : [Why sign in to Chrome](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139).

Comment: *>  copy them from `Extensions`*   -1   That won’t work. As soon as you run Chrome, the folder will be deleted from `Extensions`. Go ahead and try it and see for yourself. By simply copying it, you have not properly told Chrome about the extension and it is not in the habit of just blindly loading everything that happens to be in the `Extensiosn` directory since that would be extremely poor security design.     Syncing could/should work, but is good for your own systems; I would not want to create a new account to be shared with another person; especially if it’s a one-time use thing.

Comment: @Synetech I can't comment on syncing, but re copying the dsfsdfsdfsdsfd folder (extensions as we know, produce folder names like that), I can confirm that about chrome not seeing the extension, and deleting the folder.

Comment: Yup, Chrome has a nasty habit of blindly deleting anything and *everything* in the `Extensions` folder that is not registered in the `Preferences` file. Many people have lost extensions due to this frustrating behavior (which persists to the latest version). `☹`

Answer (score 1):

1. Downloaded the chrome extension from internet and saved it in my 'D' drive.(File extension : crx)

   [[image]

   <sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tcIR.png)
2. Then i dragged the the file from 'D' drive and dropped it on Chrome 'Manage extensions' console. It will be installed.

   [[image]

   <sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hkjb.png)

Comment: 1)how did you download the file,  i'm not sure how to do that in chrome  2)if the file is no longer online then what, you have to transfer it from another computer but your answer doesn't cover that.

Answer (score 0):

The method described by Oliver and Mohit does work. I was not able to find the Extension in the Chrome store anymore (discontinued?) but I had the *.CRX file in my Downloads folder from a previous installation (on XP computer). I transferred the file onto a new computer (Win7,  over a network). With the Chrome Extensions window open, I had the other Folder open just as the picture shows. With a simple drag-and-drop the Extension was installed in the new location!