# Chrome extension via USB

Tags: google-chrome, usb-flash-drive, google-chrome-extensions

Is it possible to download a Chrome Web Store extension onto your USB stick, plug it into another computer and use it? Chrome Web Store is blocked and there is no way of bypassing it. I want to use Foxy Proxy Standard on the computer so I can access blocked sites. I have looked online, but there seems to be no answer there...

Comment: I'm sure the sites are blocked for a reason. Speak to your IT department.

Comment: Sites such as stackoverflow are blocked. Can you see a reason behind that???

Comment: Ask your IT department why they are blocked. If you ask them nicely and say you need it for work they may unblock them for you.

Comment: But is there a way to download an extension to your USB?

Comment: Did you bother to look for an answer? What did your research tell you?

Comment: Duplicate: [How to download Chrome extensions for installing in another computer?](http://superuser.com/q/290280)

Comment: Duplicate: [Copy Chrome extensions from one computer to another](http://superuser.com/q/634648)

Comment: Duplicate: [How to copy an extension from one Chrome installation to another?](http://superuser.com/q/462804)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask): "**Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?** Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: Another option is to create a usb key with portableapps.com and install Google Chrome portable on that key and then install Foxy Proxy as needed... You can then carry that key around and launch from any Windows machine you have access to. That said, there propably is a reason for why sites are bblocked as David points out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to do this. You can download an extension's source code using CRX extension downloader and download the folder and transfer to your USB. Then you can go to `chrome://extensions/` and select developer mode on the top right. Next just click 'Load Unpacked' and select the extension folder. For most extensions this should load your own local copy of the extension on the USB and allow you to use it like normal.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple: Use a portable version of Google Chrome from a USB drive and add all extensions to it.

Link: http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable